# I'm not able to receive data from my firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm a rookie regarding firebase and android.
After reading for a while I have raise a question regarding my code:

I'm not able to read information from my firebase database.

here's my code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference referenceArtista = mDatabase.child("artists");
    final List<Pintura> pinturaList = new ArrayList<Pintura>();
    referenceArtista.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot artistaSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Artista artista = artistaSnapshot.getValue(Artista.class);
                pinturaList.addAll(artista.getPinturaList());
            }
            RecyclerView recyclerViewPintura = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            recyclerViewPintura.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerViewPintura.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getBaseContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
            AdapterPintura adapterPintura = new AdapterPintura(getBaseContext(),pinturaList);
            recyclerViewPintura.setAdapter(adapterPintura);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

My database structure looks something like this:
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fk9KM.png)

I've been debugging and I'm seeing that the list at the end of the foreach cycle, returns null. (hence I'm greeted with a NullPointerException and the app crashes)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check security rules. If requires user auth and u don't authorize ur users, remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting null because `List<Pintura> pinturaList = new ArrayList<Pintura>();` is declared outside the `onDataChange()` method. You need to declare and use it `inside that method` and outside the `for loop`, otherwise is null, due the asynchronous behaviour of the method, which is called before you even add those `Artista` class objects to the list.

To solve this, please use this code:

```
referenceArtista.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        final List<Pintura> pinturaList = new ArrayList<Pintura>();
        for (DataSnapshot artistaSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Artista artista = artistaSnapshot.getValue(Artista.class);
            pinturaList.addAll(artista.getPinturaList());
        }
        Log.d("TAG", artista); // Here is not null
        RecyclerView recyclerViewPintura = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerViewPintura.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewPintura.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getBaseContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
        AdapterPintura adapterPintura = new AdapterPintura(getBaseContext(),pinturaList);
        recyclerViewPintura.setAdapter(adapterPintura);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

If you want to use that list outside `onDataChange()` method, please see my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152775/how-to-get-value-async-in-outside-method-ondatachange).

Answer (score 0):

Can you initailize your recycler vioew in onCreate method and once you get the data from the firebase just update the adapter

```
 pinturaList = new ArrayList<Pintura>();
                        dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                        //List<User> list= new ArrayList<User>();  
                        for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                           Artista artista = artistaSnapshot.getValue(Artista.class);
                            pinturaList .add(user);
                        }  

    adapter.update(pinturaList );
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of addListenerForSingleValueEvent use ValueEventlistener then use forEach loop because single return single or null value if you have more than one

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;

private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;

 mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
 mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("YOUR TABLE NAME").getRef();


 mFirebaseDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                    Log.v("dataSnapshot.getValue()", "" + dataSnapshot.getValue());
                    for (DataSnapshot dss : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) dss.getValue();

                        //get your values

                    }  
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```